# Using pointers for string manipulation in c

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, stack, arrays

Here I'm taking a sentence a checking if it is a palindrome or not.I'm doing this in the process of learning stacks.

Is there a way i can use pointers instead of char array 'sent' so that the number of input characters need not be constrained to 20 in the following code?
The code is working fine, but should there be any improvements in terms of performance or anything else?
is there anything important about pointers i should remember while using stacks, like initializing it to NULL?
Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char data;
    struct node *link;
}StackNode;

void insertData(StackNode **);
void push(StackNode **, char);
void checkData(StackNode **);
bool pop(StackNode **,char *);

char sent[20] = "";

void main()
{
   StackNode *stackTop;
   stackTop = NULL;
   insertData(&stackTop);
   checkData(&stackTop);
   printf("\n");
   return;
}

void insertData(StackNode **stackTop)
{
    char c;
    int len;

    printf("Enter the Sentence\n");
    while( ( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n'))
    {   
        if( ( ( c>='a' &&c<='z') || (c>='A' && c<='Z')))
        {
            if((c>='A' && c<='Z'))
            {
                int rem;
                rem = c-'A';
                c='a' + rem;
            }
            push(stackTop,c);
            len = strlen(sent);
            sent[len++]=c;
            sent[len]='\0';
        }
    }
    printf("Letters are %s\n\n",sent);
}

void push(StackNode **stackTop,char c)
{
    StackNode *pNew;
    pNew = (StackNode*) malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
    if(!pNew)
    {
        printf("Error 100:Out of memory\n");
        exit(100);
    }
    pNew->data = c;
    pNew->link = *stackTop;
    *stackTop = pNew;
}

void checkData(StackNode **stackTop)
{
    char c;
    int i=0;
    while(pop(stackTop,&c))
    {
        if( c !=sent[i++])
        {
            printf("Not palindrome");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("Palindrome");
}

bool pop(StackNode **stackTop,char *c)
{
    StackNode *pNew;
    pNew = *stackTop;
    if(pNew == NULL)
        return false;
    *c = pNew->data;
    *stackTop = pNew->link;
    printf("char poped %c\n",*c);
    free(pNew);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: There is no char array anywhere in the code, and I don't see any limitation of 20 characters either. The question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to line up with your code, but you can always use pointers instead of arrays.

Comment: I'm sorry, please check it now

Comment: belongs to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to have an "infinite array" or an array with no limitations. However, if you use `malloc` you can produce a section of memory large enough that you won't need to worry about the limitations as much. I see that later on in the code you have used malloc, so I assume you know how it works. However, I would use something like this;

```
char * sent = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
if(sent == NULL){
     printf("OUT OF MEMORY!");
     return 1;
}
```

Where 100 is the buffer size you wish to have. I have used a size up to 10000 and had no problems at runtime, so that may be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In C, arrays are really pointers to statically allocated memory. It is pretty straightforward to create a pointer to an array, or any element in an array. For example, suppose we have you array `char sent[20].` If we wanted to create a pointer that pointed to the exact same memory as sent, we can declare `char *sentP = sent`. We can now replace any use of `sent` with `sentP`. We can even create a pointer to the middle of sent: `char *sentMidP = sent + 9`. Now, `sentMidP[0]` is the same as `sent[9]` and `sentMidP[-9]` is the same as `sent[0].`

However, unlike `sent`, we can change where `sentP` and `sentMidP` point (think of `sent` as a constant pointer `char * const`, which you can't change). Thus, if you had another array `char sent2[100]'. You can set the value of`sentP`to`sent2`. What's cool about this is that you can do it *at runtime*, which effectively means that you can change the size of`sentP` depending on the size of your input.

However, there is no need to limit yourself to statically allocated input. C provides the `malloc` function (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)) to allocate memory at runtime. Thus, if you don't know the size of your sentence at compile time, but you will know it at runtime (say in a variable called `sentenceLength`), you can allocate `sentP' like the following.

```
char *sentP = malloc(sizeof(char) * (sentenceLength + 1)); // Plus one for the NUL termination byte in C strings
if (sentP == NULL) {
     fprintf(stderr, "No more memory :(");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
```

Note how we now have to handle out-of-memory errors. In general, dynamic allocation introduces more overhead, because there is a possibility that we run out of memory, a requirement that we ensure we only access what was allocated, and a need to release the memory with `free` once we're done.

When you're done with the `sentP` pointer, be sure to free it with:

```
free(sentP);
```

That's it! You can use the `sentP` pointer we made in your code, and everything should work great. Good luck!